# Validating images in Spring Web + Bean Validation?

Tags: java, spring, validation

I wonder, how you complement or recommend the validation of an image using Spring Web + Bean Validation (@Valid). For already I googled a lot and some solutions were to be desired.
Restrictions for image validation, which is a mandatory field MultipartFile type are:
* Not accept empty value;
* Accept only extensions .png / jpeg / jpg.

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Here is what you need in an example, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7161215/spring-multipartfile-validation-and-conversion

Comment: Obrigado, deu certo.