# @Valid annotation is ignored when applied to MultipartFile object

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-validator, spring-mvc-initbinders

This is my controller. It accepts a `multipart/form-data` request with two fields, `form` and `file`. The `form` field is a 
`MyObject`, the `file` field is a `MultipartFile`. Both variables are annotated with `@Valid`, and accordingly, I would expect Spring to invoke the `Validator` class of each respective field. However, this only happens with `MyObject`, and *not* with `MultipartFile`.

```
@RequestMapping("/api")
@RestController
public class Controller {

    private MyObjectRepository repo;
    private MyObjectValidator myObjectValidator;
    private FileValidator fileValidator;

    @Autowired
    public myObjectController(MyObjectRepository repo, MyObjectValidator myObjectValidator,
                              FileValidator fileValidator) {
        this.repo = repo;
        this.myObjectValidator = myObjectValidator;
        this.fileValidator = fileValidator;
    }

    @InitBinder("form")
    public void initMyObjectBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
        binder.setValidator(this.myObjectValidator);
    }

    @InitBinder("file")
    public void initFileBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
        binder.setValidator(this.fileValidator);
    }

    @PostMapping("myObject")
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
    @ResponseBody
    public MyObject createMyObject(@RequestPart("form") @Valid MyObject myObject,
                                   @RequestPart("file") @Valid MultipartFile... file) {
        return repo.save(myObject);
    }
}
```

My `MyObjectValidator` is triggered, but my `FileValidator` is not triggered. Both classes implement the Spring `Validator` interface. `MyObjectValidator.supports(Class<?> aClass)` *is* called, whereas `FileValidator.supports(Class<?> aClass)` is *never* called. Apart from that, my `Controller` is functioning perfectly, and diligently saves objects to my `repo`.

What could be the issue here? I've read similar questions, and common mistakes are to not use an appropriate argument inside the `@InitBinder` annotation, or to set the `@InitBinder` methods to `private` instead of `public`, but neither of this applies to my case.

This ugly workaround does what it's supposed to, but it is un-Spring-like. I call my `FileValidator` manually inside the `Controller.createMyObject` method, instead of letting Spring call it automatically through the `@Valid` annotation.

```
@PostMapping("myObject")
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
@ResponseBody
public MyObject createMyObject(@RequestPart("form") @Valid MyObject myObject,
                               @RequestPart("file") @Valid MultipartFile... file) {
    if (fileValidator.supports(file.getClass())) {
        Errors errors = new BeanPropertyBindingResult(file, "Uploaded file.");
        fileValidator.validate(file,errors);
        if (errors.hasErrors()) {
            throw new BadRequestException();
        }
    }
    return repo.save(myObject);
}
```

---

EDIT: I have included my `Validator` classes on request.

```
import org.springframework.validation.Validator;

public abstract class AbstractValidator implements Validator {
    // One shared method here.
}
```

```
public class FileValidator extends AbstractValidator {

    public boolean supports(Class<?> aClass) { // This method is never triggered.
        boolean isSingleFile = MultipartFile.class.isAssignableFrom(aClass); // This line has a breakpoint, it is never triggered in the debugger.
        boolean isFileArray = aClass.equals(MultipartFile[].class);
        return (isSingleFile || isFileArray);
    }

    public void validate(Object o, Errors e) {
        //Several validation methods go here.
    }
```

```
public class MyObjectValidator extends AbstractValidator {

    public boolean supports(Class<?> aClass) { // This method is triggered.
        return (MyObject.class.equals(aClass)); // This line has a breakpoint, and it is always triggered in the debugger.
    }

    public void validate(Object o, Errors e) {
        // Several validation methods go here.
    }
```

---

EDIT: I made some changes to my code like NiVeR suggested, removing the varargs parameter and changing my `FileValidator.supports(Class<?> aClass)` accordingly, but the behavior is still the same.

In Controller.java:

```
@PostMapping("myObject")
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
@ResponseBody
public MyObject createMyObject(@RequestPart("form") @Valid MyObject myObject, @RequestPart("file") @Valid MultipartFile file) {
    return repo.save(myObject);
}
```

In FileValidator.java:

```
public boolean supports(Class<?> aClass) {
    return MultipartFile.class.isAssignableFrom(aClass);
}
```

Comment: You should show the codes of the validators also..

Comment: @NiVeR, I edited the question.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the problem is related to the variadic `Multipart...` parameter. In the `supports` method of the validator you are checking for array of `Multipart` but I suspect that's not the correct way. Just as a trial, I would make the `Multipart` a single object parameter (and change the validator accordingly) to test if it works in this way.

Comment: I tried this now, but it made no difference. I appended my question with your suggested edits. Just for the record, my `supports` method in `FileValidator` does not only check for an array, but for a single `MultipartFile` object as well. If the input is either of those two types, the value will get accepted. Either way, my `supports` method is never even called. The breakpoint inside that method is never triggered.

Comment: Ok, second idea: create a wrapper class which includes the `Multipart` as a property, and implement the validator on that other class instead (passing it as a parameter to the controller as well).

Comment: It seems complicated to craft an HTTP request that my Spring controller will accept and convert into the wrapper class. Is this something I should use as a solution, or only for diagnosis? Is there some easy way to do this?

On a side note, I just edited my question with an ugly workaround that does work, sort of, but it is un-Spring-like. This workaround also reinforces my hypothesis that nothing is wrong with the `FileValidator` itself, but only the binding.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7161215/spring-multipartfile-validation-and-conversion

Answer (score 0):

@Magnus I think you have to add annotation in all the Validator Class
eg.

```
@Component
public class MyObjectValidator extends AbstractValidator {

    public boolean supports(Class<?> aClass) { //This method is triggered.
        return (MyObject.class.equals(aClass));
    }

    public void validate(Object o, Errors e) {
        //Several validation methods goes here.
    }
}
```

Comment: Finished testing it. I first set the `@Component` in my `FileValidator` and `MyObjectValidator`, and then I set it in my `AbstractValidator` as well. No effect. Then I tried removing the `@Component` from `FileValidator` and `MyObjectValidator`, but left it in `AbstractValidator`. It still did not make any difference.

Comment: Magnus I think you forgot to add the @Controller in Controller class can you do it once if that works for you.

Comment: I accidentally omitted it from the question, but the @Controller annotation is there. See my edit. As mentioned, this is a functioning controller, except that the `FileValidator` class is never invoked.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not actual, but you should add @Validated at class level:

```
@RequestMapping("/api")
@RestController
@Validated
public class Controller {

    private MyObjectRepository repo;
    private MyObjectValidator myObjectValidator;
    private FileValidator fileValidator;

    //rest of your code here
}
```

And you don't need @Valid at method attributes level anymore.