# Custom constraint validation annotation for MultipartFile

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I'm trying to make an annotation to validate a list of `MultipartFile` on the controller parameters, but it doesn't seem to make any effect. No exception is thrown, not error at all.
I looked at some similar questions but it didn't work.

- Interface:

  ```
  @Target(ElementType.PARAMETER)
  @Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
  @Constraint(validatedBy = {ImageValidator.class})
  public @interface ValidImage {
    String message() default "Invalid image file";

    Class<?>[] groups() default {};

    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
  }
  ```
- Class:

  ```
  public class ImageValidator implements ConstraintValidator<ValidImage, List<MultipartFile>> {

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(
        List<MultipartFile> listMultipartFile, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {

      for (var multipartFile : listMultipartFile) {
        var contentType = multipartFile.getContentType();
        if (!isSupportedContentType(contentType)) {
          context.disableDefaultConstraintViolation();
          context
              .buildConstraintViolationWithTemplate("Only JPG and PNG images are allowed.")
              .addConstraintViolation();
          return false;
        }
      }

      return true;
    }

    private boolean isSupportedContentType(String contentType) {
      var supportedContents = List.of("image/jpg", "image/jpeg", "image/png");
      return supportedContents.contains(contentType);
    }
  }
  ```
- Usage:

  ```
  @PostMapping(value = "images")
    public ResponseEntity<List<ExerciseImageDTO>> uploadImages(
        @RequestParam(value = "images", required = true) @ValidImage List<@Valid MultipartFile> images) {

      .......
      return ResponseEntity.ok(createdImages);
    }
  ```

Comment: You short of something to convert MultipartFile into images in post action. pls implement Converter to make it firstly. refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7161215/spring-multipartfile-validation-and-conversion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need `@Validated` on your controller class like this

```
    @Controller
    @Validated
    public class SampleController {

      @PostMapping(value = "images")
      public ResponseEntity<List<ExerciseImageDTO>> uploadImages(
      @RequestParam(value = "images", required = true) @ValidImage List<@Valid MultipartFile> images) {
        .......
        return ResponseEntity.ok(createdImages);
      }

    }
```